# xampp error while loading shared libraries

Tags: php, xampp

Just adding this for myself and others future reference.

Installed xampp for the first time and was getting this error when trying to run the startup script.

```
error while loading shared libraries: libc.so.6
```

The work around is to change the kernel version in the /opt/lampp/xampp script

```
##export LD_ASSUME_KERNEL=2.2.5
export LD_ASSUME_KERNEL=3.11.6
```

xampp script is sets redhat kernel to 2.2.5  but mine is 3.11.6 found as follows

```
[root@2008pc etc]# rpm -q kernel
kernel-3.11.6-200.fc19.x86_64
```

Comment: Found very useful after got stuck into the issue. Thanks Gary!

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you can find error at line number 50 in lampp script, it should looks like following:

```
if egrep "Fedora" /etc/redhat-release > /dev/null
```

For CentOS we need to replace Fedora with CentOS, after changing like looks like following:

```
if egrep "CentOS" /etc/redhat-release > /dev/null
```

After making above changes try to start lampp with following and it should work without any issue.

```
$ /opt/lampp/lampp start
```

or

```
./lampp start
```

where /opt/lampp is root directory of lampp server.

Comment: Great.  Thanks Shafeeq for the additional info.